# MINLP optimization with matlab reaching different solutions every run

Tags: optimization, matlab, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have written a program for optimizing a set of generators. I have hourly price and cost data and need to figure out when a generator should run or just stay off. I describe the problem in more detail below. I have programed this using matlabs global optimization toolbox and the ga solver. I run the solver and each time I run the solver I get a different solution. I am thinking this is because ga is no able to properly search the solution space for an optimal solution? Is it unable to cope with the use of $x_3$ to turn the generator off?

The solver stops with this status:

> Optimization terminated: average change in the penalty fitness value
>   less than options.TolFun and constraint violation is less than
>   options.TolCon.

**Problem Description**

$x_1$ is the generator output at any one point in time and is constrained to be between a min and max capacity

$x_2$ is an integer variable used simply to turn the generator off completely

$x_3$ lastly is another integer variable used to apply a startup cost whenever the generator is switched on.

**Objective Function (totrevenue6):**

$efficiency6 = 0.2621*x_1 - 0.1229*x_1^2 + 0.2543$

$income6 = \frac{-x_1*(AC_1 + FC_1 - P_1 + FC_1)}{efficiency6}$

$revenue6 = - SC_1*x_3 - x_2*(income6)$

**totrevenue6** = -sum(revenue6)

**Constraints:**

- min_capacity <= generator6 power ($x_1$) <= max_capacity
- 0 <= generator6 toggle ($x_2$)<= 1
- The startup constraint ($x_3$) is $x_j-x_{j-1}<=s_j$ and rearranging
  $-x_{j-1}+x_j-s_j<=0$
- 0 <= ($x_3$)<= 1

So my question(s)
why does ga solver reach a new solution every time I run it? How do I get the solver to solve this type of problem?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

ga does not garantee an optimal solution.
However you can heuristically tune ga parameters (generation number, initial individuals, crossing factor...) to finish near the value you want.
Check the help of *ga* and *opimset* for more details.